# retrieve signed key from source code without building

Tags: android, eclipse

i uploaded my app in a market 1 month ago ! 
now i want to update my app but the market show me this error :

> " Package must be signed with the same key as the previous packages "

But i dont know about sign key ! 
i need to retrive this code to update my app ! 
i have a backup from my source code with old sign key but when i build new version i think that bulding make new sign key to my app !

**how can i get this code from my source or my old apk file ?
if i can find this key , how can i import it to my app ?
i work in eclipse ide!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i dont know about sign key !

[You signed your app](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing-eclipse.html) before you uploaded it to the Play Store.

> how can i get this code from my source or my old apk file ?

You cannot get it from the APK file. Whether you put your release keystore in your source code or not, I cannot say.

> if i can find this key , how can i import it to my app ?

You use the keystore from [the signing wizard in Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing-eclipse.html).

Comment: thanks. i wish give another site from developers because this site blocked iran and i cant access . np i will use freegate ;)